# mysql joins on multiple table depending on the value of column

Tags: mysql

I am using a post table and two type of entities school and user can add something to this table. post table has a post_from field to differentiate whether post is from user or school.

i want to write one query with join to user table or school table depending on post_from field.

```
SELECT *
FROM post    
LEFT JOIN `user`
ON (user.id = post.uid AND post.post_type = 'user' )
LEFT JOIN school_profile
ON (school_profile.id = post.school_id AND post.post_type  = 'school')
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: At first glance that looks like it should work. Does it not? What goes wrong / what's the error? And what's the benefit of selecting these all in one go as opposed to running two separate queries - some ordering? something else?

Comment: user and school fields are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a union :

```
SELECT post.*
FROM post    
INNER RJOIN `user`
ON (user.id = post.uid AND post.post_type = 'user' )

union

SELECT post.*
FROM post    
INNER JOIN school_profile
ON (school_profile.id = post.school_id AND post.post_type  = 'school')
```

Alternatively, you can do this :

```
SELECT *
FROM post    
LEFT JOIN `user` ON (user.id = post.uid)
LEFT JOIN school_profile ON (school_profile.id = post.school_id)
WHERE post.post_type IN ('user', 'shcool')
```